# To get the items from the list based on todays date

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

```
private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
```

> Error: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Promise iam getting an error. The above 'Error' is my error statement.

Comment: In your case you need to return the promise of ISPLists from your function.

Comment: yes that the error its showing. So what do i do for that?

Comment: Can you post the complete code? At least the _getListData() function.